# Distribute public key to all pods in all namespaces automatically

Tags: kubernetes

I have a public key that all my pods needs to have.

My initial thought was to create a ConfigMap or Secret to hold it but as far as I can tell neither of those can be used across namespaces. Apart from that, it's really boiler plate to paste the same volume into all my Deployments

So now I'm left with only, in my opinion, bad alternatives such as creating the same ConfigMap/Secret in all Namespaces and do the copy-paste thing in deployments.

Any other alternatives?

Extra information after questions.

- The key doesn't need to be kept secret, it's a public key, but it needs to be distributed in a trusted way.
- It won't rotate often but when it happens all images can't be re-built.
- Almost all images/pods needs this key and there will be hundreds of images/pods.

Comment: I guess you've looked at https://appscode.com/products/kubed/0.5.0/guides/config-syncer/intra-cluster/

Comment: Yes, that and similar agents that move stuff around. It surprises me that this isn't something built in and it feels like I've must have missed something.

Comment: Questions: do you need to keep the key secret (confidential)? Do you need to rotate it often? Are there many distinct deployments (images) that need the key? Do you build the images for the deployments that need the key?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Kubernetes initializers to intercept object creation and mutate as you want. This can solve copy-paste in all your deployments and you can manage it from a central location.

https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-kubernetes-initializers-work-22f6586e1589

You will still need to create configmaps/secrets per namespace though.

Comment: Perhaps I can also intercept the creation of the configmap to fork it into all namespaces ...

Answer (score 0):

While I don't really like the idea, one of the ways to solve it could be an init container that populates a volume with key(s) you need and then these volumes can be mounted in your containers as you see fit. That way it becomes independent of how you namespace stuff and relies only on how pods are defined/created.

That said, the Kubed mentioned by Ryan above sounds like more reasonable approach to a case like this one, and last but not least, something creates your namespaces after all, so having the creation of required elements of a namespace inside the same process sounds legit as well.

Comment: For that init container to be able to fetch the configmap/secret it still needs to be distributed to all namespaces, right?